# How to obfuscate URLs in ASP.NET MVC to prevent image download?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, image, download

So far, I have a jQuery solution to prevent right-clicking images and any possible appearance of a "context menu" that allows file download:

```
$("img").each(function () {
    $(this).contextmenu(null, function () {
        /* preventing the "context menu" that appears after a right-click,
         * or whatever other possible way through the keyboard: */
        return false;
    });
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        if (e.button === 2) {
            // preventing right-click:
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The user may still right-click any other part of the page though, view the source code, and then have access to to the file through the `img src` as per usual.

---

I don't want to disable right-clicking on the entire document, and in my Googling these seem like possibilities:

- put the images in the `App_Data` folder? (*...getting a 404 error when

  trying to access something like `App_Data/Images/foobar.jpg`*)
- add something like this to `Web.config`? (*...not doing anything*):

```
  <location path="Content/Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

So is it possible to obfuscate the URL that displays in the source code some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is not easily, if you send it to the browser in an HTML document the file must be accessible and the user will be able to retrieve it. If the images are extremely important you can use a flash gallery or java applet both have their own problems though when you talk about mass access. Flash not being ran on phones and java applets being seen as security risk.

Now if your trying to get crazy you could create a mechanism of creating URLs on the fly and only serving them once but this would require you to have every IMG URL make calls to a database to store then create your own file sender through routing. Sorry this might not be clear i am typing this from a phone on my couch :).

This method isn't full proof because the browsers cache everything so if someone wants it bad enough they will get it. If your only trying to make it harder so the average person won't this could do it.

The last thing to consider is any action like this could be bad for seo. You do not want Google getting 404s on every image they crawl.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @DrewGoldsberry -- that's a great point about actions like these being potentially bad for SEO. For this reason, I think I should let the images be openly accessible and focus more on copyrighting. I'll have to look into these methods you are describing!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever consider using a Generic Handler to do the job? This way you don´t need to store images in a place accessible to user.
Here are some examples i used in asp.net c#:

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/859d32c8-945d-4e5d-8c89-775388598f62.aspx
http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/asp-net/how-to-download-files-from-server-to-client-using-a-generic-handler/

I Know the thread is old but i hope this helps.